# Europe/Paris -> CET; Asia/Hong_Kong- > HKT; Europe/Moscow -> MSK

Tags: python-3.x

how can i convert 'timmezones' to 'human readable' format in python3?

I.e.:

```
Europe/Paris -> CET;
Asia/Hong_Kong- > HKT;
Europe/Moscow -> MSK
```

Thank you a lot for any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris').tzname(datetime.datetime(2018,1,1))
'CET'
>>> pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris').tzname(datetime.datetime(2018,7,1))
'CEST'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> tz_cet=pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris')
>>> now1=datetime.datetime.now(tz_cet)
>>> now1.strftime('timezone is %Z')
'timezone is CET'
>>> tz_hkt=pytz.timezone('Asia/Hong_Kong')
>>> now2=datetime.datetime.now(tz_hkt)
>>> now2.strftime('timezone is %Z')
'timezone is HKT'
```